# How to get MySQL back on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mysql

The upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 delete MySQL and I need urgently to get it back. The problem is that I'm getting an error installing it, either with apt-get or aptitude:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've already tried different ways to install MySQL but without success, as reported in this thread at the Forum:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998260

I believe I should file a bug, but following the instructions I thought better to ask here first.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: could try **apt-get install -f**

Comment: I tried to install mysql with alien, but the results is about the same. Since I can't post the details here, I ask you to check the Ubuntu Forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12022579&postcount=8 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to install mysql server following the tip by konrad, using `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the log carefully, you see that the problem is that there is a package called `libmysqlclient-dev` with the version `5.5.23-1~dotdeb.0` which provides the file `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_example.so`. So, it seems that you had mysql installed from http://www.dotdeb.org. Try removing those packages first. You can find out which packages are from there using the following:

```
aptitude search "?installed?origin(packages.dotdeb.org)"
```

Remove them and then also remove the corresponding entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Run `apt-get update` and then re-try installing your MySQL server.

Comment: Where can I find the log you mentioned? Will try it as you say.

Comment: Ok, first of all thank you for replying to my question. Where's what I tried: $ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep dotdeb.org
# deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all # disabled on upgrade to precise
# deb-src http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all # disabled on upgrade to precise
$ sudo aptitude search "?installed?origin(dotdeb.org)"
$ sudo aptitude search "?installed?origin(php53.dotdeb.org)" It seems that indeed I had PHP packages installed from dotdeb.org but running the search you suggested I'm not getting any results. In any case, why would PHP packages interfere with MySQL?

Comment: What does `dpkg -S /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_example.so` tell you?

Comment: The log I was referring to was the command line log you posted on the Ubuntu forum.

Comment: Here it is: 

$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_example.so
libmysqlclient-dev: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_example.so

If I understand it correctly you are saying this has to go. I believe I already tried that:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12016658&postcount=6

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Got caught with this one as well, with dependency failures when trying to run "apt-get -f install" but I found a different way out:

```
:~# aptitude install mysql-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server 
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 323 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.5 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,024 B will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but    5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 is installed.
 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Remove the following packages:
1)     mysql-server                
2)     mysql-server-5.5            



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdbd-mysql-perl{u} libdbi-perl{u} libmysqlclient18{u} 
  libnet-daemon-perl{u} libplrpc-perl{u} libterm-readkey-perl{u} 
  mysql-client-5.5{u} mysql-client-core-5.5{u} mysql-common{u} 
  mysql-server{a} mysql-server-5.5{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 11 to remove and 317 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 76.9 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 215864 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server ...
Removing mysql-server-5.5 ...
mysql stop/waiting
Removing mysql-client-5.5 ...
Removing libdbd-mysql-perl ...
Removing libdbi-perl ...
Removing libmysqlclient18:amd64 ...
Removing libplrpc-perl ...
Removing libnet-daemon-perl ...
Removing libterm-readkey-perl ...
Removing mysql-client-core-5.5 ...
Removing mysql-common ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

Current status: 0 broken [-1], 317 updates [-7].
:~# apt-get install mysql-server
```

And, after that the install (e.g. would-be upgrade) went in cleanly.

Hope that helps others.

Answer (score 0):

not sure that this will help but after upgrading to 12.04 and facing the same issues you guys did, I took a look at the error.log file and found this:

```
130508 12:09:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130508 12:09:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130508 12:09:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130508 12:09:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130508 12:09:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
130508 12:09:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130508 12:09:04 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130508 12:09:04  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130508 12:09:05 InnoDB: 5.5.31 started; log sequence number 569709903822
130508 12:09:05 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'log_bin_trust_routine_creators=1'
130508 12:09:05 [ERROR] Aborting
```

after commenting out 'log_bin_trust_routine_creators=1' it worked like a charm. apparently this is a deprecated option from mysql 5.1 and not recognized by 5.5

hope it helps.

Cheers