# Unable to install mysql under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: dpkg, mysql, software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get MySQL back on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149289/how-to-get-mysql-back-on-ubuntu-12-04)

i'm getting the following error when trying to install MySQL Server under Ubuntu:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.22-0ubuntu1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
 Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error    from         a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried all kinds of solutions I had found on the web, but none of them works: I've tried `apt-get purge mysql-server* mysql-common`, I've deleted all directories, I've tried installing by `apt-get install -f mysql-server`, I checked `dpkg -S` and also `dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.5`

More info:

```
Kernel : 3.0.8+
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Hardware : MK802 ( a chip ARM )
login as root with password
```

Comment: I try to reinstall mysql from a fresh unbuntu LTS 12.04 ... but i've got the same error ...

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the [.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/98956154/mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) file from launchpad and install it.

Comment: ok, i try this and tell you if it's ok.

Comment: It's i386 version you give me, have you the arm version ?

Comment: Check these links http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-main-i386/mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb.html  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcepub/2354786/+listing-archive-extra

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe i miss something ? But i'm on arm proc. so i386 doesn't work on my linux. On the website i don't find a mysql-server armel version. Can you confirm ? Pierre

Comment: Check this [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/5.5.22-0ubuntu1/+build/3369418)

Comment: Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.020-1build2) ...
    Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.22-0ubuntu1) ...
    Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.22-0ubuntu1) ...
    ... blablablabla
    start: Job failed to start
    invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
    dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned     error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     mysql-server-5.5
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Same error... i clean properly before and use your deb.

Comment: Maybe it's a direction. The install failed but when i start mysqld by command line i have got this : "Can't create IP socket: Permission denied"